# Wordpress Theme: Remove Navigation Bar

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been trying to set up [this theme](http://www.dezzain.com/wordpress-themes/mesocolumn/) on my wordpress installation, and I'm having a bit of trouble customizing it. I want to remove [this bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNoM8.jpg) from the top of my website completely. I've been playing with the code, but I can't figure it out. All I manage to do is break the theme, and then I have to reinstall it. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Find in style.css line 681 `#top-navigation` then add `display:none` before the closing `}` or hack away to try remove the html

Answer (score 2):

To actually "remove" the navigation,
Go to header.php and delete line number 66 to 88 `(<nav> to </nav>)`